# How to multiupdate using mongoose update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have four documents in mongodb.

```
// first document
  {
    "id": 1,
    "exist": true
  }
// second document
  {
    "id": 2,
    "exist": false
  }
// third document
  {
    "id": 3,
    "exist": false
  }
// forth document
  {
    "id": 4,
    "exist": false
  }
```

I want to update like this. It's because only one document can have true value.

```
// first document
  {
    "id": 1,
    "exist": false
  }
// second document
  {
    "id": 2,
    "exist": false
  }
// third document
  {
    "id": 3,
    "exist": true
  }
// forth document
  {
    "id": 4,
    "exist": false
  }
```

How can I make a query using mongoose in nodejs? Thank you so much for reading it.
I want to resolve this by only one query not multiple query.

Comment: Can you post some of efforts/code then only we can help you.

Comment: I can only make findOneAndUpdate using mongoose. like findOneAndUpdate({exist:true},{exist:false}). BUt I don't know How can I make multiple update.

Comment: @DDDD : Do you've any specific document in all 4 one to be `true` or any random one can become `true` &  also mongoDB version?

Comment: I can choose one that I want to make be true by "id". For example, I want to make id:4 as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, things can be achieved in one DB call :

```
db.yourCollectionName.bulkWrite([
    {
        updateMany:
        {
            "filter": {},
            "update": { $set: { "exist": false } }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne:
        {
            "filter": { id: 4 },
            "update": { $set: { "exist": true } }
        }
    }
])
```

Or you can try this, maybe this can be faster as it's searching for a filter, could be on index, though first query doesn't really update all docs but has to scan thru all :

```
db.yourCollectionName.bulkWrite( [
   { updateMany :
      {
         "filter" : {"exist" : true},
         "update" : {$set :{"exist" : false}}    
      }
   },
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter" : {id:4},
         "update" : {$set :{"exist" : true}}    
      }
   }
])
```

**Ref :** [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#examples)

Comment: Thank you for aswering my question. But the problem is when I run this only modified one document as first matching document. So updateMany and next updateOne doesn't work. Is this my problem?

Comment: @DDDD  : Didn’t get that can you please paste your query in comment box..

Comment: In my case, I have multiple filter option. So maybe I make different filter like $filter: [{}]?

Comment: @DDDD  where do you’ve multiple filter option ? In updateMany ?

Comment: @DDDD  : what all your filter options do you need can you give sample doc and required output? Or did you already make it work?? Or maybe if you need much help you can raise a new question and ping it here if it’s a big deal needed some help..

Comment: for example, i made 'filter: {exist: true, visible: true}'

Comment: @DDDD  actually I’m still confused which part is not working is updateMany not updating docs ? Or updateOne not working or entire query is throwing error or you need help in writing code to pass filters to query? Maybe if you think this query is working in ideal scenario and got stuck with anything new please raise a new question and ping link here..

Comment: Ah my db works like this. There are many documents having "exist: true". Even though when I run this query, it update only one document as exist false. I used updateMany

Comment: @DDDD  : So with filter :{exist : true, visible:true} there might be only one document in db, So updateMany is updating only one doc !! Check If that’s the case...or do you’ve any documents where exist field doesn’t exist?? Basic way to test is by doing .find() on ur filter query to see your docs returned.